# How do I draw a box in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I want to draw a box around a portion of my graphic for the purpose of highlighting it.

How can I do that?

Comment: On the gimp documentation, they recommend using InkScape for drawing shapes . They say "GIMP is not designed to be used for drawing". https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-using-rectangular.html. But the answer below is the one I went with, perfect for a simple rectangle.

Comment: Gimp can be thought of as FOSS adobe Photoshop, whereas Inkscape is FOSS adobe Illustrator. Photoshop/Gimp is for raster/photo editing, whereas Illustrator/Inkscape is for vector/illustration editing.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Use the rectangle selection box, and under the *Edit* menu, hit *Stroke Selection*. Select your options from there, and hit "Stroke" to apply the stroke.

Comment: GIMP is a powerful piece of software and as such has a pretty steep learning curve.

For quicker, easier tasks I would recommend Paint.Net.  Think of it as MSPaint++.

Comment: I've never used Paint.Net myself, but have heard nothing but praise about it.

Comment: GUI of GIMP is a disaster. I simply can never find the buttons to do whatever I need to do. Having to Google how to make a rectangle says it all I think!

Comment: How about gimpShop? Can that be something?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no Paint.Net for Linux :(

Comment: paint.net is propitiatory non-free-software.

Comment: @JohnyTex I also find the GIMP UI disgusting to an extreme, but, in all fairness, drawing a box in Photoshop isn't all that straightforward as well.

Comment: Kolourpaint is very close to paint on Ubuntu.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The Stroke Selection option is greyed out. @Marc – it's dead-easy in photoshop... choose the shapes tool (make sure it's a square using long click), then draw your square. What could be easier?

Comment: I can't understand that I have to spent 15 minutes searching for answers how to draw a friggin square in Gimp. No wonder it is not widely used. Did developers try to make this painful on purpose?

Comment: @geoidesic , you need to use the `Rectangle Selection` tool first to draw a square. Only then, you can go to the menu `Edit -> Stroke Selection`

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I follow these instructions, but the box never appears.  The 'Stroke Selection' dialog is set to a visible number of pixels in width, solid line, and the foreground color is black, so it should be visible.  Is this answer missing something?

Comment: Any chance we can update this answer for the always-in-flux UI, in which now none of the directions make sense?  For gimp v2.10.34, I see "Rectangle select" under Tools -> Selection Tools ... and then under Edit -> Stroke Selection.

Answer (score 64):

Select `Filters > Render > Gfig...` From there you can draw boxes and other shapes boxes in various styles.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Gfig opens a dialogue box with a whole bunch of things inside, none of which are clickable. It all just seems to be disabled. The only UI element that worked on that box was the close button.

Comment: @geoidesic I can confirm it working for Ubuntu 18.04.1 using GIMP 2.10.8

Comment: Actually I've noticed a few other dialog boxes suffering from the same problem on Mac OS X Mojave. Alt tabbing a few times seems to unblock the dialog box and allows one to edit.

Comment: It works, but strangely. For example, I draw a square box in a picture and the box does appear, but smaller then what is drawn in the preview. Nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: It's really hard to select location accurately from that small preview box.

Comment: The lines for the box are comically large. This is completely useless.

Answer (score 18):

Use the box select tool, then Select >> Border
This selects around your current selection's outline (dotted animated line), at a distance of however many pixels you enter in the dialog box *on either side* of original line. 
i.e. if you use 5 for Border's input value, you will have a 10 px wide border selected. Then fill it in with paint bucket. You now have a box. 
Or... fill a layer with any colour, pattern, gradient, image etc., and use the selection to create a black box in a white layer mask using the same selection. Select all on layer mask, and gaussian blur a bit. That will give you a blurred border, using whatever image is on the layer. Everything that is black on the layer mask will be transparent to the layer below.
Using this image as the main layer, I created a thick blurred border, but started with a circle selection instead of a square. I also did a border select on the original border select (after filling in layer mask) to blur the edges of my new border, and not the whole border.

Original:
[image: http://www.theblaze.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Kim-Jong-Un-AP.jpg]

New Border
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHzjr.png]

Example using black layer instead of image, and rounded corners.
[image: http://i61.tinypic.com/2yovj0j.png]

Comment: no, no, no ... too many politics :)

Comment: lol this made me crack up at work xD

Comment: This tells you what you can do, but not how to do it :-|

Comment: This answer is wrong, you can't fill a selection with the paint bucket. Once you click the paint bucket tool, the selection disappears.

Comment: It also says "use the selection to create a black box in a white layer mask" but it doesn't tell you how. Select just draws a selection, it doesn't allow you to "create a black box in a white layer mask". If we knew how to "create a black box" then we wouldn't be asking this question!

Answer (score 14):

[@Aeo](https://superuser.com/users/40192) answer is not clear enough:

1. First use the **Rectangle Selection** to draw your rectangle/box
   [image]
   [image]
2. Only then, go under the **Edit** menu, and hit **Stroke Selection**.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. This is the most helpful answer here.

Answer (score 1):

After going through all these convoluted answers, I figured out a simpler one.

Create a new layer.
Set the opacity to 50%.
Set your foreground color to yellow (or whatever).
Click the Rectangle Select tool.
Draw a box around the text you want to highlight.
Don't hit enter. Go immediately to the edit tab, and select Fill with foreground Color. Hit enter.
Ta Da!

Answer (score 0):

**Create keyboard shortcuts for it**

If you are using this a lot, create custom keyboard shortcuts for it as mentioned at: https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-concepts-shortcuts.html

- Edit
- Preferences
- Interface
- Configure keyboard shortcuts

Then, search for: "Stroke Selection".

Two possibilities open up, and I set:

- "Stroke Selection": "Ctrl + Alt + ,"
- "Stroke Selection...": "Ctrl + Alt + ."

These are inspired by the similar predefined fill shortcuts "Ctrl + ," and "Ctrl + .".

Now:

- "Ctrl + Alt + .": used for the first stroke. This opens the menu of stroke properties, from which you can select stroke parameters such as line width.
- "Ctrl + Alt + ,": strokes immediately with the previously selected stroke properties

Also note that you can make multiple rectangular strokes at once by selecting multiple rectangular selections at once by holding Shift:

[image]

and then after "Ctrl + Alt + ," it immediately becomes:

[image]

Tested on Gimp 2.10.18.